# Unable to find bean of certain type while autowiring in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

Before I start, please assume that the `pom.xml` is faultless.

Having said that, let's proceed,

The error I am getting is below:

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>   *************************** Description:
>
> Field empDao in com.sagarp.employee.EmployeeService **required a bean of
>   type 'com.sagarp.employee.EmployeeDao' that could not be found**.

Now the `spring boot application` class is as below:

```
package com.sagarp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient //this is for eureka which not our concern right now.
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sagarp.*") //Included all packages
public class EmployeeHibernateApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeeHibernateApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The `EmployeeService` class is as below:

```
package com.sagarp.employee;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDao empDao; // interface

    public EmployeeDao getEmpDao() {
        return empDao;
    }

    public void setEmpDao(EmployeeDao empDao) {
        this.empDao = empDao;
    }
    //some methods
}
```

> Please note that `EmployeeDao` is an interface.

`EmployeeDao` interface is as below:

```
public interface EmployeeDao {
    //Oh! so many methods to I have provided
}
```

`EmployeeDaoImpl` class which implements `EmployeeDao` interface.

```
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    //Oh!So many methods I had to implement
}
```

I guess due to the reason `EmployeeService` is annonated with `@Service` it is autowired automatically.
I added all the packages in `components` sothat it will scan and instantiate all the dependancies I might have.

But it did not, hence the issue.

Could anyone help me with the error with the above details.
Please let me know if any more details required.

Comment: Try annotating the `EmployeeDaoImpl` class with `@Repository` .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, It works now, but it is spawning issue with `sessionFactory.`

Comment: @sagarpatro Mark an answer as correct and ask another question with the content requested in as in comments by others.

Comment: With the `sessionFactory` issue. Feel free to create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmployeeDaoImpl` is not registered as a bean. There are two ways: XML or annotations. Since you already use annotations, here you go:

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    //...
}
```

Note you already registered `EmployeeService` as a bean with `@Service`. After this, the bean should be recognized in the container and properly injected.

Why `@Repository` for DAO and not `@Service` again? How to decide? Read the [Baeldung's](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-repository-service) article for more information.

- `@Component` is a generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component
- `@Service` annotates classes at the service layer
- `@Repository` annotates classes at the persistence layer, which will act as a database repository

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, It works now, but it is spawing issue with `sessionFactory`.

Comment: This is another question which is not related to the repository issue. For this, you have to provide the content of EmployeeDaoImpl.java class.

Answer (score 1):

Component Scan searches for Classes that are annotated with Spring Stereotype annotations. In order for a class to be eligible for auto-wiring it must have one of these annotations.

The solution is to annotate EmployeeDaoImpl with either @Component, @Service, or @Repository.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, It works now, but it is spawning issue with `sessionFactory.`

Answer (score 1):

EmployeeDaoImpl should also be annotated.

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   //Oh!So many methods I had to implement
}
```

This should solve the issue.